# mongo shell collection.find by _id does not work

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to fetch doc using _id but it returns nothing in mongo shell.When I check collection it has that _id.

```
> db.Client.find({_id:"5b76f488fb83e109b3a399d9"})
> db.Client.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b76f488fb83e109b3a399d9"),
    "emailHost" : "Gmail",
    "name" : "ABC DEF",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-08-17T16:15:04.907Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-08-17T16:15:04.907Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b76f48efb83e109b3a399db"),
    "emailHost" : "Gmail",
    "name" : "ABC DEF",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-08-17T16:15:10.635Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-08-17T16:15:10.635Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I don't understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping _id in ObjectId()

```
> db.test.find({"_id" : ObjectId("4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c")})

> db.test.find(ObjectId("4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your query does not work is because `_id` is not a string. It is an object of type `ObjectId`. You can create one by calling `ObjectId("4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c")`.

That would result in the following query:

```
db.Client.find({_id: ObjectId("5b76f488fb83e109b3a399d9")})
```